# Вывести char arrray из функции

Tags: c, функции, arduino, char

Есть функция:

```
  const char* get_name_of_weekday(uint8_t dayIdx){
     switch (dayIdx){
      case 1:
        return "понедельник"; 
        break;
      case 2:
        return "вторник"; 
        break;   
      case 3:
        return "среда"; 
        break;
      case 4:
        return "четверг"; 
        break;      
      case 5:
        return "пятница"; 
        break;   
      case 6:
        return "суббота"; 
        break;
      case 7:
        return "воскресенье"; 
        break;            
     }
     return "Unknown";
  }
```

И есть её вызов:

```
const char weekDay[] = get_name_of_weekday(_TODAY_DAY_);
```

Пишет ошибку при компиляции:

> initializer fails to determine size of 'weekDay'

Где я накосячил и как исправить?

Comment: Замените `const char weekDay[]` на `const char* weekDay`

Comment: Проблема в том, что массивы должны инициализироваться *во время компиляции* — вот как, например, *компилятору* узнать, какой размер памяти выделить под `weekDay`?...

Comment: Окей, а как тогда переделать

Comment: Чтоб после в printf запихнуть?

Comment: @Harry, не подскажите?

Comment: Поменяйте тип `weekDay`, чтобы он соответствовал типу возвращаемого значения функции, вот и все.

Comment: Так ведь KoVadim написал, как. Я же просто пояснил, почему.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Инициализируя переменную `weekDay` типа `const char[]` значением типа `const char*` вы допускаете ошибку в том, что `weekDay` - это массив, размер которого должен быть известен при компиляции (для того, чтобы компилятор знал, сколько памяти необходимо для него выделить).

Компилятор не может определить его размер из типа возвращаемого значения функции, о чем и выдает вам ошибку.

Решение заключается в замене типа переменной `weekDay` с `const char[]`

```cpp
const char weekDay[] = get_name_of_weekday(_TODAY_DAY_);
```

на `const char*`

```cpp
const char* weekDay = get_name_of_weekday(_TODAY_DAY_);
```

Comment: Поскольку TS возвращает указатель на **статическую** область, я бы рекомендовал очень внимательно прочесть вот это: https://coderoad.ru/890535/%D0%92-%D1%87%D0%B5%D0%BC-%D1%80%D0%B0%D0%B7%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%86%D0%B0-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B4%D1%83-char-const-%D0%B8-const-char

Comment: а я бы очень строго рекомендовал не давать ссылку на сайты-автопереводы, а давать нормальную ссылку на оригинал https://stackoverflow.com/questions/890535/what-is-the-difference-between-char-const-and-const-char